# Connecting Outlook into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-automation, com-automation

New to programming and trying to create this project for work. I have a text file inputted that has a list of usernames. I want the code to take the usernames from the text file and look them up in Outlook to give me a "true" or "false" if there is a match for the user in the system. How do I connect Outlook to the code with MAPI or an API? The code I have so far is below.

```
namespace QC_OUTLOOK
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static object MessageBox;
        private static object objFile;
        private static int i;
        private static object Strings;
        private static object response;

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Documents\QC\User_list.txt";

            // string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText(filePath));

                foreach (String line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            {
                Outlook._Application oApp = new OutLook.Application();
                //Get MAPI namespace
                Outlook.AddressLists oNS = oNS.AddressLists;
                Outlook.AddressList oGal = oALs.Item("Global Address List");
                //Get all entries
                Outlook.AddressEntries oEntries = oGal.AddressEntries;
                // Get first user found 
                Outlook.AddressEntry oEntry = oEntries.GetFirst();
                Outlook_UserName_Output = "";

                response = sa.GetAllUsers;
                Console.WriteLine(response);
        //
                UserCount = 0;
                UsersFound = 0;
                LastNameMatches = 0;
                InactiveUser_Count = 0;
                Inconsistent_EmailAddrs  = 0;
                GIS_UserCount = 0;
                TodaysDate = DateTime.Today;
                object value = objFile.WriteLine("Date:" + TodaysDate);
                object value1 = objFile.WriteLine("QC_UserID, QC_FullName, OutLook_Last_Name, OutLook_First_Name");
                for (i = 1; i <= Strings.Len(response) ; i++);

                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

                // Get the MAPI namespace.
                Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

                oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);


                Outlook.MAPIFolder oInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);


            }

        
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
                dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
                

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items OutlookItems;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder Folder_Contacts = (MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
                OutlookItems = Folder_Contacts.Items;

                foreach (var item in OutlookItems)
                {
                    var contact = item as ContactItem;
                    if (contact != null)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["FirstName"] = contact.FirstName;
                    dr["LastName"] = contact.LastName;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, creating a new Outlook Application instance multiple times in the code is not the best way to go:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

Outlook is a singleton. You can't run two instances of Outlook on the system at the same time. So, I'd suggest keeping the application object and re-use it where possible.

Iterating over all items in the Outlook folder is not really a good idea. Instead, use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook Contact items using Restrict method](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/21/outlook-retrieve-contact-items/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext to retrieve Outlook Contact items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/19/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-contacts/)

But better is to use the [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method which creates a `Recipient` object and can be used to verify a given name against an address book. The [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method attempts to resolve a created `Recipient` object against the Address Book. That's exactly what you are looking for!

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your response. I was able to connect Outlook through the VSTO, but now am having trouble with it not reading the textfile to look the users in Outlook. This is my code below.

Comment: Where is your code? Did you try to run it under the debugger attached? Anyway, sounds like this is a separate questions not related to Outlook at all. Please don't forget to mark the answer.